Can I steal if it's my stuff
So a little while ago, I dated this one girl. She cheated on me, and after that my watch just went missing. My watch is a prized possession that I got after graduating. I searched everywhere for it, and cannot find it. I usually wear it, but there are times were I take it off and put in in a PARTICULAR part of my bag. She knows this. She would deny it if I confront her, but I'm 90% positive she has it. Should I steal it back?

Another possible dupllicate: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/88429/has-anyone-been-charged-for-stealing-their-own-stuff?rq=1

The details depend on the jurisdiction you are in, but generally, when you take your own property you are not stealing it. However, you might be trespassing during the search for your own property, for instance, even if that search is ultimately successful. And if it comes to a confrontation in the place of your girlfriend, the legal consequences for you could be even worse.
If you are sure, talk to the police. If the police are convinced there is a case, they will ask for a search warrant and do a legal search.
That means you have to convince them. "I'm always careful with my stuff, so it must have been stolen" is not sound reasoning. Even careful people misplace things.

Whether something was a gift in the first place and whether one can change their mind about a gift are asked and answered at other Q&As on this site. And how one would go about proving a version of events is addressed here: How do you prove a fact in litigation? 

What happens if the girlfriend claims that she was given the items in question and that it was just a matter of changing their mind on giving the items?

"you cannot steal your own property" is confusing. You presumably intended it as "If you take your own property, it's not stealing", but it could be read as "you're not allowed to steal your own property". SNL had a sketch where a bunch of nuclear reactor techs were confused when their retiring supervisor left them with the instruction "You can't put too much water in a nuclear reactor."
